# zipline: target_order not executed in handle_data

Tags: python, zipline

I'm trying to develop a monthly rotational trading strategy with Zipline and data from the Quandl bundle.
The strategy is supposed to hold a number ("topn") of assets with the highest momentum score and hold them until they dropped below a certain momentum rank ("keepn").

When I run the following code through zipline, it works for a couple of months, then suddenly starts holding more and more positions, selling the same positions repeatedly without actually removing the positions from the portfolio. This happens with Quandl data as well as with a custom bundle.

I'm guessing, there's a fundamental flaw in my strategy, but going through debugging, I really can't find it.

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you.

Dirk

```
def initialize(context):
    # List of all assets to chose from  
    context.tickers = ["AAPL", "YELP", "YHOO", "MMM", 
                       "ABT", "AMD", "AMZN", "GOOG", 
                       "AXP", "AMGN", "BBY", "BLK", 
                       "CAT"]

    context.universe = [symbol(ticker) for ticker in context.tickers]
    context.momentum_lookback = 256

    # Hold (topn) 3 assets, as long as they are in the (keepn) top 5 momentum_rank
    context.topn = 3
    context.keepn = 5

    # Schedule the trading routine for once per month
    schedule_function(handle_data, date_rules.month_start(), time_rules.market_close())

    # Allow no leverage
   set_max_leverage = 1.0


def momentum_score(ts):
    # Simplified momentum score: Last price / price 256 days ago 
    return ts[-1] / ts[0]


def handle_data(context, data):
    # String with today's date for logging purposes
    today = get_datetime().date().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

    # Create 256 days (context.momentum_lookup) history for all equities
    hist = data.history(context.universe, 
                              "close", 
                              context.momentum_lookback,
                              "1d")

    # How much to hold of each equity
    target_percent = 100 / context.topn

    # Rank ETFs by momentum score
    ranking_table = hist.apply(momentum_score).sort_values(ascending=False)
    top_assets = ranking_table[:context.topn]
    grace_assets = ranking_table[:context.keepn]

    # List of equities being held in current portfolio
    kept_positions = list(context.portfolio.positions.keys())

    # Sell logic
    # ==========
    # Sell current holdings no longer in grace assets
    for holding in context.portfolio.positions:
        if holding not in grace_assets:
            if data.can_trade(holding):
                print(today + " [Sell] "+holding.symbol)
                order_target_percent(holding, 0.0)
                kept_positions.remove(holding)

    # Buy Logic
    # =========
    # Determine how many new assets to buy
    replacements = context.topn - len(kept_positions) 

    # Remove currently held positions from the top list
    buy_list = ranking_table.loc[~ranking_table.index.isin(kept_positions)][:replacements]

    # Buy new entities and rebalance "kept_positions" to the desired weights
    new_portfolio = list(buy_list.index) + kept_positions

    # Buy/rebalance assets
    for asset in new_portfolio:
        if data.can_trade(asset):
            print(today+"[BUY] "+asset.symbol)
            order_target_percent(asset, target_percent)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured out what the problem is. Basic math failure on my end.
This is the troublesome code:

```
# How much to hold of each equity  
target_percent = 100 / context.topn
```

It should have been `target_percent context.topn / 100` instead. *facepalm*
I'm assuming this leads to situations in which orders aren't filled properly, leading to the described behavior.

Lesson learned:

- Check for open orders and cancel them, if needed
- Keep an eye on leverage and position sizes and check against restrictions during the algo run